# CSS div extend to fit image

Tags: css

I use the following code in an effort to create two divs, a big grey one and one in it that also has an image on the right. Code works good but both divs don't extend to where the image ends... How can I fix this?

```
<style>
div.div1 {
background-color: #F1F1F1;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
padding: 10px;
}
div.div2 {
background-color: #e2d8ba;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 10px;
text-align: justify;
}
</style>
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2">
<img src="http://www.dailyrecoverymeditations.com/forums/image.php?u=2057&dateline=1404850818" style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;">
Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image is a floated element, add `overflow: auto;` to both DIVs:

```css
div.div1 {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.div2 {
  background-color: #e2d8ba;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://www.dailyrecoverymeditations.com/forums/image.php?u=2057&dateline=1404850818" style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;"> Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `float` an element, you [remove it from the normal flow of the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). If you want the parent to extend to fit the height of the floated element, you need to implement a "clearfix" to "clear" the float. You can read all about floats here - https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

There are many techniques for clearing floats, so I added one as a `.clearfix` class that you can use on any parent with floated children.

```html
<style>
  .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  div.div1 {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  div.div2 {
    background-color: #e2d8ba;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
  }
</style>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2 clearfix">
    <img src="http://www.dailyrecoverymeditations.com/forums/image.php?u=2057&dateline=1404850818" style="float:right; padding-left: 10px;"> Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing Text Testing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*CSS*/
div.div2 {
    overflow: auto;
}

/*OR*/
div.div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```